# Generate XElement code from XML string

Tags: c#, code-generation, xelement

Is there any way to generate the `XElement` representation in C# from a given XML string?

Basically what I want to achieve is going from a string like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>RSS Channel Title</title>
    <description>RSS Channel Description.</description>
    <link>http://aspiring-technology.com</link>
    <item>
      <title>First article title</title>
      <description>First Article Description</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

To a string like this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
   new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
   new XElement("rss", 
       new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
       new XElement ("channel",
           new XElement("title", "RSS Channel Title"),
           new XElement("description", "RSS Channel Description."),
           new XElement("link", "http://aspiring-technology.com"),
           new XElement("item",
               new XElement("title", "First article title"),
               new XElement("description", "First Article Description")
           )
       )
    );
```

Really appreciate any hints!

Comment: As I understand you are trying to build a code generator. You could possibly mention a keyword "code generation" to avoid misleading answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [XElement/XDocument Code Generator](http://www.dexterlegaspi.com/journal/?p=96).
It generates c# code from XML using XSLT transformation.
If I would do it myself I'll probably do it the same way.

Comment: This seems to be very near to want I want to achieve. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper 2016.1 has a context action to convert string to XElement or XDocument object.

[image: gif example how it works]

Comment: Pls add that descriptive to view - you have to put "!" in front of the line.